# Add another module activity to manifest

Tags: android

I have been working on a project and I need to use android-crop library. I have imported this module in my application, https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop but it consists of an activity, and according to the docs i have to add the activity tag in my manifest file,

but after adding this line in my manifest file,

```
<activity android:name="com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageActivity"/>
```

I am getting cannot resolve symbol "CropImageActivity" error.
How can i add this activity in my manifest.

Comment: Since it is a part of another module.

Comment: Are you exporting your imported project with current one

Comment: have tou added the dependency `compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'` correctly? And have you had a successful sync after adding the dependency?

Comment: i have added and the project is compile, it is visible in android window

Comment: Should us how you have added it to `build.gradle` because this should be working. Also you should paste the stacktrace so we can see where the error is originating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the following steps.

```
1.file->new->Import Module.
after import module
2.file->Project Structure->app->dependency tab-> add library dependencies(example and lib).
3.In build.gradle(module:example) change to apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

if you get any error regarding min and target sdk versions, then choose 4th step other wise exclude 4th step(first 3 step enough).

```
4.file->Project Structure->example ->Flavors tab //change minimum and target sdk versions().
```